# How to make react-chartjs-2 responsive on mobile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using react-chartjs-2 in a project of mine and I cannot find the problem of the chart, because on mobile all the labels and legend are still big af. I tried `responsive: true`, `maintainAspectRation: true`. Nothing works

[image: This is how it shows on a small device]

Comment: I've wasted **days** on these silly parameters, you have my sympathy.. Horrible (!!!) API. Have you tried giving the parent element, which the chart renders in, a fixed height?

Comment: @vsync Yes, tried the fixed height. It works up to a certain point, which isn't on mobile. Somehow I should use transform: scale(), but it will blur out the pixels. On their website works [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html). Don't know what's different

Answer (score 14):

I've made you a [demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/RqmeaZ) page of how I've made my charjs responsive.

Basically you need to give the `<canvas>` element `height:100%` and pass these options:

```
options: {
  maintainAspectRatio : false
}
```

Do not use `responsive: true` at all, it doesn't seem to do anything.

If you'r `<canvas>` is inside some container, I would suggest making that container responsive (with flexbox for example).

Comment: That solved the graph, but what about the labels and legend? They still remain same size, despite being on a smaller size. On a pie chart for example, because the legend is inside the canvas, the width will consider those elements too, so the graph will stay small, while de legend is bigger

Comment: This is why I'm against `<canvas>`.. you cannot style things from CSS like for `SVG`. what I did for the legend is to disable it from the options and render it myself with _HTML_.  Regarding the labels, that's difficult to manage if not impossible. But you didn't ask about labels in your title or description, therefor I have answered the question to the point.

Comment: That's a good idea. You did helped solve my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem on my nextjs app. My Bar Chart was not rendering properly on mobile viewport. 
 
I perused the main [ChartJS docs on responsiveness](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html) and there's a part they talk about [resizing the chart canvas when its container resizes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note). In my case, the container is just a div. Hence In order to fix the issue on mobile viewport, I set my div to be relatively positioned and also set view width and height but it messes up chartjs rendering on desktop screens
hence I had a CSS style that resets my **height** and **width** to auto on screens greater than 767px. 
Also, I set option `maintainAspectRatio : false` as per the chartJS docs.

```
#canvas-container {
    height: 60vh;
    width: 60vw;
    position: relative;
 }

 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     #canvas-container {
         height: auto;
         width: auto;
      }
 }

<div id="canvas-container">
 <Bar options={options} data={data}/>
</div>
```

Do not forget to set option `maintainAspectRatio : false` 
You can check out the main example from ChartJS Docs [here](https://codepen.io/chartjs/pen/YVWZbz). Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You can force to re-render your widget on window resize. Here i use the `useWindowSize` hook from [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useWindowSize.md)

```
export function App() {
  useWindowSize();
  ...
  return <Bar key={Date.now} options={options} data={data} />;
}
```